# Setting work directory parallel to program directory

Tags: python, directory

I have written a program and compiled it which edits CSV files. I don't want to put there a working directory in the code I want the program to edit the CSV files when they are parallel to the program directory.

E.g.:

Path to program: C:\Programs\CSVEditor
Path of CSVs: C:\Programs

But the CSVEditor and the files could be anywhere on the workstation or on a server and I want it to work anywhere...can someone understand what I wanna say?

Does anybody has an idea what I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Forget what I wrote before. I want to have an dialog where I can set the working path.

Answer (score 0):

Put the CSVEditor script's directory onto your [Path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). That way, no matter where you are, you can type this at the command line:

```
csv_editor.py my_file.csv
```